# How to enlarge icons in KF5 Plasma panel's System Tray?

Tags: icons, notification-area, kde-plasma-5

I've upgraded from Kubuntu 14.04 to 18.04. I've set up most of the icons via System Settings *Icons* section to larger size and made Plasma panel thicker. But system tray icons, instead of becoming larger, simply arranged in two rows, where each icon is tiny (16x16 px).

I've tried looking in the system tray settings dialog, tried going through System Settings multiple times, including *Icons* and *Workspace Theme* sections, but failed to find a setting for this.

How can I make System Tray icons larger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this thread](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/increase-the-size-of-tray-icons-kde/12449) I've found a solution (workaround?):

- In the file `~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`, locate a line starting with `extraItems=`.
- After that line, append a new line with text `iconSize=3`
- The above might need to be repeated for each `extraItems=` line if there are more (I had only one) — according to the link above
- Save the file
- Restart Plasma shell: `killall plasmashell ; kstart plasmashell`

After Plasma started again, my system tray now has normal-sized icons in a single row.